# MVC3 on godaddy

Tags: godaddy, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm trying to publish my site on the godaddy. I also spoke to their technical staff. Basically, I published my site to a local directory on my system (C:/test) and then copied all the resultant files from them on to my root folder on GoDaddy. However, I cannot reach my application!!! The technical guy mentioned that GoDaddy only understands index.html files as the startup. I am not sure how to resolve this. Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: You did get a Windows Hosting account right?

Comment: Yes, I am with their 4GH hosting which supports MVC3 , Asp.net 4.0 and iis 7.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If the account only supports index.html, it does not support any asp.net. Upgrade.

Comment: TO be honest, I htink the techie guy had no idea what I was talking about.

Comment: So, WE should knot withou even knowing what you ahve at godaddy? Sorry, critstal balls are out.

Comment: Whoa, why the unnessary sarcarsm.  My apologies I forgot to mention the hosting I've got.  Doesn't warrant  your comment though

Comment: While TomTom does (often) come across as sarcastic, he does have a point, we're not psychic. When asking questions on SF it's best to add as much info as possible, even if it doesn't seem that useful.